# jQuery live html editor not working?

Tags: jquery

I was trying to make a simple html editor, but it is not working.
It should show all of the HTML and CSS inputted in the iframe every time you press a key, but it isn't
This is my code

```
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var frame = $('iframe'),
                contents = frame.contents(),
                body = contents.find('body'),
                styleTag = contents
                    .find('head')
                    .append('<style></style>')
                    .children('style');

            $('textarea').focus(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.keyup(function() {
                    if ( $this.attr('id') == 'html') {
                        body.html( $this.val() );
                    } else {
                        styleTag.text( $this.val() );
                    }
                });
            });
        }) ();
    </script>
<body>
    <textarea id="html"></textarea>
    <textarea id="css"></textarea>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at `$.parseHTML()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/ ... you can do stuff like `$.parseHTML($(this).val())` and then work with it in terms of DOM

Comment: This worked in this guy's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhODHoaats0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't see what's inside an iframe. Iframe contents can't interact with outer page's contents. //Edit: previous applies when iframe is from different domain (thanks for the video.)

Your script should be declared AFTER the DOM it wants to parse. otherwise you should use $.ready() to ensure that the page is completely loaded when you execute your function. Yu are defining the function that tries to find DOM elements before those elements actually exist.

This works:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  // <----- 'cause of $().ready()
        var frame = $('iframe'),
            contents = frame.contents(),
            body = contents.find('body'),
            styleTag = contents
                .find('head')
                .append('<style></style>')
                .children('style');

        $('textarea').focus(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.change(function() {
                if ( $this.attr('id') == 'html') {
                    body.html( $this.val() );
                } else {
                    styleTag.text( $this.val() );
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! please note that it's allowed "...if the iframe is on the same domain..."